# compilation errors with template function definition

Tags: c++, templates

So I'm trying to make a template for a red-black tree, but I can't figure out why some of the functions won't compile.  Here's the specification:

```
template <class myType>
class redBlackTree
{
private:
    enum treeTraversalOptions {INORDER, PREORDER, POSTORDER, NONE};
    enum nodeColor {RED, BLACK};
    struct nodeType
    {
        myType keyValue;
        nodeColor color;
        unsigned int wrdCount;
        nodeType *left;
        nodeType *right;
        nodeType *parent;
    };
    nodeType *root;
    void destroyTree(nodeType *);
    unsigned int countNodes(nodeType *) const;
    unsigned int height(nodeType *) const;
    nodeType * incCount(myType, nodeType *) const;
    unsigned int getWordCount(myType, nodeType *) const;
    void getMaxNode(nodeType *, unsigned int &, std::string &);
    void printTree(nodeType *, treeTraversalOptions) const;
    nodeType * rightRotate(nodeType *);
    nodeType * leftRotate(nodeType *);
public:
    redBlackTree();
    ~redBlackTree();
    void destroyTree();
    unsigned int countNodes() const;
    void getMaxNode(unsigned int &, std::string &);
    unsigned int height() const;
    bool incCount(myType) const;
    unsigned int getWordCount(myType) const;
    void printTree(treeTraversalOptions) const;
    void insert(myType);
};
```

And here's one of the problem functions:

```
template <class MyType>
unsigned int redBlackTree<myType>::getWordCount(myType word, nodeType *treeNode) const
{
    if (treeNode)
    {
        if (treeNode->keyValue == word)
            return treeNode->wrdCount;
        else if (word < treeNode->keyValue)
            getWordCount(word, treeNode->left);
        else
            getWordCount(word, treeNode->right);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I'm getting are: 'myType' was not declared in this scope,
template argument 1 is invalid, and template declaration of 'unsigned int getWordCount'.

I've tried adding typename and scope resolution operators in places, but I just don't get why it isn't working.

Comment: try to change `MyType` -> `myType`

Comment: Voted to close since the error is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `MyType` in some places and used `myType` in other places.

You could fix it by changing

```
template <class MyType>
```

to

```
template <class myType>
```

or the general convention in the standard library at least is to just use

```
template <class T>
```

It helps to distinguish your templated type from a conventional variables somewhat.

Comment: Thank you so much! I must be going blind after staring at this so long :)